# Page scrolls to top of text box instead of cursor position

Tags: firefox, chatgpt

The site in question is chat.openai.com.

I've encountered a problem where, upon pasting approximately 400 lines of code, the vertical scrollbar does not automatically scroll down to reveal the cursor. Instead, it jumps to the top of the text box, necessitating manual scrolling. Even hotkeys like Ctrl+End don't solve the issue as they only change the cursor position, not the scrollbar position.

Is there a known solution to address this behavior?

Comment: 1. Scrolling will often work *within a frame* or other page subdivision, as selected by cursor hover. For example, if the mouse hovers over one area, the wheel will scroll *that* area and not another. Perhaps the cursor must be on a specific area. 2. Sometimes, HTML in the page may prevent scrolling. If that issue also occurs in other browsers, e.g., Chrome or Brave, then the issue is in the coding for the site.